# Binding Gridview from stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures, datagrid, webforms

I bound my `gridview` (`dgvresult2`) reading data from a stored procedure. When I debug my `gridview.rows.count` it is zero though my `DataSet` table has 5 rows (`ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count`).

Kindly assist with this - below is my code:

```
private void ReturnResult ( )
{
        try
        {
            string connetionString = null;
            lblcino.Text = "1234";

        connetionString = "Data Source= SLB-84NKBT1\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=WireLine Tracking Assets; User=admin; pwd=password123";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);

        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("GetCIno", connection);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.Add("@CustomerInvoiceNo", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = lblcino.Text; //((Label)dgvresult.FooterRow.FindControl("lblcino")).Text;

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        da.Fill(ds);

        if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                dgvresult2.DataSource = ds;
                dgvresult2.DataBind();
                dgvresult2.Visible = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            string message = "ds is Empty";
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Popup", "ShowPopup('" + message + "');", true);
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did add if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                dgvresult2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                dgvresult2.DataBind();
                dgvresult2.Visible = true;
            }

Comment: but griedview still empty

Comment: Can you post the markup of your GridView from your .aspx file?

Comment: @ Andera Found Solution SET GRIEDVIEW AUTO GENERATE == TRUE